# How to realize - FMX TVirtualkeyboard inside TPanel Delphi Seattle 10 on Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: keyboard, firemonkey, delphi-xe

AControl is a TPanel

`procedure TDialogAccess.CheckVirtualKeyboard(const AControl: TFmxObject; Edit: TEdit);
begin
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) then
  begin
  if not assigned(ikeyboard) then ikeyboard :=  TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
  if assigned(ikeyboard) then
    begin
    if  not (TVirtualKeyboardState.Visible  in ikeyboard.VirtualKeyboardState)  then
      begin
       ikeyboard.ShowVirtualKeyboard(AControl);
       Edit.SetFocus;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;`

TVirtualkeyboard is shown in a seperate Window, how to get it as Child of a Panel?
You have to click the Edit Control, that TVirtualkeyboard realizes the target for inputs, how to do this programmatically??

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pretend like child component for Panel. But if you need a keyboard when you click any input field, you can create keyboard on different panel which is child for your panel. You can do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  keyboardPanel.Visible := True;

  //.. Your codes here

end;
```

And your Structure must be like this:

```
Form1
 Panel1
  KeyboardPanel
   KeyboardInputsButtons
```